# Splitting comma separated value in a column into multiple columns in SQL Procedure

Tags: oracle, plsql

I run a procedure as follows.

```
 PROCEDURE LOAD_SPM_ITEM_SYNC(P_ENCODED_STRING IN CLOB,truncateflag in varchar2) IS 
output varchar2(30000);
BEGIN
if (truncateflag='true') then
execute immediate 'truncate table SPM_ITEM_SYNC';
end if;
output:=utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(utl_encode.base64_decode(utl_raw.cast_to_raw(P_ENCODED_STRING)));
dbms_output.put_line(output);
insert into demo(column_1)
select regexp_substr(output, '[^'||CHR(10)||CHR(13)||']+', 1, level) 
from dual 
connect by regexp_substr(output, '[^'||CHR(10)||CHR(13)||']+', 1, level) is not null;
end LOAD_SPM_ITEM_SYNC;
```

The above procedure takes an encoded string of a CSV as input as inserts it into a table.

Sample encoded string is MSwyLDMKMSwyLDMKMSwyLDM=

Output after running the procedure:

```
column_1 column_2 column_3
1,2,3    
1,2,3
1,2,3
```

But my requirement is

```
column_1 column_2 column_3
1        2        3
1        2        3
1        2        3
```

I tried to split column_1 using SPLIT_PART but it is not working. I tried with string_split but still, it is failing and giving an error.  Where should I modify the code to insert values into different columns?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
insert into demo(column_1)
```

inserts values into a single column, not `3` different columns. It means that you'll have to split the string. How? Using `SUBSTR` + `INSTR` (lines #4 - 10) or regular expressions (lines #13 - 15), for example.

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select '1,2,3' from dual)
  3  select -- SUBSTR + INSTR
  4         substr(col, 1, instr(col, ',', 1, 1) - 1) col1,
  5         --
  6         substr(col, instr(col, ',', 1, 1) + 1,
  7                     instr(col, ',', 1, 2) - instr(col, ',', 1, 1) - 1
  8               ) col2,
  9         --
 10         substr(col, instr(col, ',', 1, 2) + 1) col3,
 11         --
 12         -- REGEXP
 13         regexp_substr(col, '\d+', 1, 1) col1r,
 14         regexp_substr(col, '\d+', 1, 2) col2r,
 15         regexp_substr(col, '\d+', 1, 3) col3r
 16  from test;

C C C C C C
- - - - - -
1 2 3 1 2 3

SQL>
```

Then insert each of them into its own column, so:

```
insert into demo (column_1, column_2, column_3) values (col1, col2, col3)
```

---

BTW, I don't know what "`split_part`" nor "`string_split`" are.

Comment: Hi @Littlefoot, i see you have taken string '1,2,3' as input but can it be generic? Because I might be getting 1000's of rows data in encoded format. If you don't mind can you just edit my existing code to insert into multiple columns?